# Linq Match Array to List?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<string>` and a `FileInfo[]`. I need to know if the entire contents of the `FileInfo[]` are in the `List<string>`. What is the most LINQy and error-free way to do that?

I was doing this, based on responses here, it returns false however, I expected it to return true:

```
        // I want to know if all of these files are in the directory
        List<string> allFilesWanted = new List<string>();
        allFilesWanted.Add( "a1.txt" );
        allFilesWanted.Add( "a2.txt" );

        // Simulate a list of files obtained from the directory
        FileInfo[] someFiles = new FileInfo[3];
        someFiles[0] = new FileInfo("a1.txt");
        someFiles[1] = new FileInfo( "a2.txt" );
        someFiles[2] = new FileInfo( "notinlist.txt" );

        // This returns "false" when I would expect it to return "true"
        bool all = someFiles.All( fi => allFilesWanted.Contains<string>( fi.Name ) );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With your updated question:

```
var filenames=HashSet<string>(list);
fileInfoArray.All(fi=>filenames.Contains(fi.Name));
```

You might need to replace `Name` with `FullName` depending on what your `HashSet` contains.

And there is the issue of case sensitivity. You can supply a custom equality comparer when creating the hashset to achieve a case insensitive comparison(such as `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`). The problem is that you can't know if a filename is case sensitive or not. That depends on the used file system. And even if you know it's case insensitive the locale used for case insensitive compares can vary.

---

Or just with Linq:

```
!fileInfoArray.Select(fi=>fi.Name).Except(list).Any();
```

`Except` uses a HashSet internally, so this is O(n)

Comment: You don't have to lose the `Except`; you can do  `!fileInfoArray.Select(f => f.FullName).Except(list).Any()`

Comment: @Ani Thanks for the hint. But there was no need to delete your answer, especially since mine was lacking a pure linq solution working with `FileInfo` and `String`

Comment: I also made a mistake (I reversed the query). You'd answered with `Except` before I could edit, so I decided to give it up :)

Comment: Note: You can use a `StringComparer` with `Except` as well (you mention it only with `HashSet`).

Answer (score 1):

```
myFileInfoArray.All(fi => myList.Contains(fi));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> fileNames = ... 
FileInfo[] fileInfos = ...  

var missing = fileInfos.Except(fileNames);
var anyMissing = fileInfos.Except(fileNames).Any()
```